# Good Ruby process pool manager

Tags: ruby, multithreading, process, fork, ipc

I need a process pool manager for MRI, with multiple worker subprocesses which in turn contain a number of worker threads. With good signal handling already built-in (that it kills all the threads in all the child processes, handles graceful/non-graceful quit and so on). Pretty much every Ruby webserver already has one, but I was wondering if there are canned gems offering this kind of pooling?

Comment: https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid or https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool maybe?

Comment: celluloid implies an actor model whereas I am looking for a more traditional pool. The connection pool is for managing cross-thread resources like sockets, so not quite what I need.

Comment: Celluloid is dead (or mostly dead). Check out [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby). It has some [thread pools](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/file.thread_pools.html) which may be what you want.